# Vacant judgeship as affecting proceedings

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage, as

I have a question about a possible error in this [phrase](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/28/143):

> Vacant judgeship ***as affecting*** proceedings

Even taking into account the fact that the phrase is a title and therefore the rules of block English should apply, the part "*as affecting*" seems a bit off.  I a have feeling that it should be "*as affects*", and the the title should instead read:

> Vacant judgeship ***as affects*** proceedings

What do native speakers think?  Should it be "*as affects*" or "*as affecting*"?

Comment: You'll probably need a lawyer to answer this, as it seems like some form of legalese. Personally I think "Vacant judgeship as it affects proceedings" or "Vacant judgeship and its effect on proceedings" is clearer, but I'm not too familiar with legal jargon.

Comment: I think the intent is "Vacant judgeship (seen) as affecting proceedings", though maybe in legalese it is OK as is. You might ask on Law SE.

Comment: @user3169 So, it is poorly worded for laymen?

Comment: It is just my guess. I wouldn't say it is poorly worded, but is probably like headlinese, where implied words can be omitted for brevity or to fit in limited space. However, to understand what the "implied" words are, you may need to understand the writing styles used in specialized fields (such as law).

Answer (score 1):

**Vacant judgeship as affecting proceedings**

The original **as affecting** is not incorrect and [has a long pedigree](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22as%20affecting%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1600,cd_max:1747&lr=lang_en); it can be paraphrased in this less pithy manner:

*Vacant judgeship in respect to the effect it has upon proceedings.*

Compare:

> Drought, as affecting crop yield.
>
> Drought, as affects crop yield.

The participle phrase can be parsed as a post-positioned nominal modifier whereas your proposed version is clausal and lacks an explicit subject for the tensed verb **affects**, requiring us to silently supply **it**:

Drought, as (it) affects crop yield.